# How to fix "Chrome couldn't load plugin" flash error?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, plugins

I've been trying numerous things over the course of a couple of months where this problem started, like :

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/_AUhHQ-t-fE

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/kU5XoT53ZTI

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/SoNvK2S27IY/QCfZTl1MCgAJ

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6086368?hl=en&vid=0-603322537270-1478270843400

I also tried launching chrome as admin, added Everyone in pepperflash security options with full privileges. Nothing has worked so far. Flash simply refuses to play on many websites. I can't even load a pdf, it displays this message. I don't have suspicious plugins installed (like adblock etc). Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the problem. I noticed that I had two flash version APIs installed: NPAPI & PPAPI.  I found out that NPAPI is now deprecated, so I uninstalled it. Now I have only PPAPI. I have tested this for about 5 days now and everything seems to work fine ever since I uninstalled NPAPI. Hopefully this may help someone.

**Back from the future**

The solution above was the real deal (and found it myself).

Answer (score 0):

Open Chrome and Go to "Advanced Settings" (Settings > Show Advanced Settings). Now click "Content Settings" button under Privacy section. In the end, go to Plugins section, click "Manage individual plugins" button and disable “Shockwave Flash 14.0 r0“.

I encountered the similar error and got rid of it by disabling this "Shockwave Flash 14.0" plugin. This happens when two different versions of Shockwave Flash works at the same time.